# Is Udemy course material copyrighted

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Udemy claims that all the videos and course content are copyrighted, but does that also hold for the material of the course?

For example, could someone use an app from a Udemy course as a starting point for a commercial project without acquiring a license from the course author?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between "content" and "material" is, but that doesn't really matter for the answer.

Comment: In this context "Content" would mean the videos, or lectures whereas "material" would have more of an intellectual meaning for example if the lecture is about Photoshop, content would be the lecture video itself and the material would be the filter for editing images that was created in the lecture. You're right, t is not important, but I just wanted to clear that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Udemy claims that all the videos and course content are copyrighted, but does that also hold for the material of the course?

Yes, all the material is copyrighted.  Ideas are not, material and content is.

> it would be really useful to me if I could take a large part of that code ... I want to know if I am allowed, by the law, to use this code for commercial purposes, or is it protected as the intellectual property?

Yes, it is protected, specifically it has copyright applied and you may only use it if the license it is distributed under allows you to - in some cases this may be a permissive license, or the code may be obtainable legitimately from another source under a permissive license, in which case its usable.

But in many cases, it may not be distributed under a permissive license or indeed any license, and in such cases you will not be permitted to use it.

The license under which the code is released depends on the individual course, and in many cases the source code repository or download site for the code for the course.  Check their for a license.